# Replace all the Null value in a column with space or 'X' in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a requirement that -
Replace the column null values with 'X' or space in postgresql
Note: this is while performing join condition, I cant update the table

Can someone help me?

Comment: (1). You can update tables in Postgres while joining to other tables. See http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-update-join/. (2). Do you need to actually update the data, or simply display `NULL`s as a space or "X"? I would argue that it's better to keep the nulls (easier to look for them, and your aggregates will be easier), and have a view that `COALESCE`s your nulls as needed.

Comment: [`COALESCE(your_column, 'X')`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/f84b4/3) should do the trick, no?

Answer (score 0):

If it is not a data manipulation operation, so it's a query. Thus, it would like to use 
[Functions Conditionals in PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL).

For this specific case, and suppose that you have a JOIN operation betwwen two tables "MyTableA" and "MyTableB" with common column keys "MyKey_A" and "MyKey_B" respectly, and you want to replace the existing NULL values of the column "MyColumn" with character 'X', you may use:

```
SELECT COALESCE(A.MyColumn,'X') 
FROM MyTableA A 
  JOIN MyTableB B ON A.MyKey_A = B.MyKey_B
```